# Meaning of 2 datasets having different distributions and why can't a neural network work on them together?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, distribution

I am using different projects datasets with input features (depth of inheritance tree, number of children, number of methods), where these features have values per class in each different project.
I have read many papers saying that a neural network or any other model can't work on datasets of different distributions

My question is:
1. what is the meaning of datasets with different distributions (where a single dataset has a number of samples, each sample corresponding to a class in that project)
2. Why NN or any algorithm can't work on 2 datasets of different distributions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most used assumptions when formulating a statistical learning probelm is that the samples are IID, this means that your samples are identically distributed, thus all the sample should came from the ssame distribution. When you say that you have two different dataets, it means that this assumption is not true, and the majority of theoritical guarantes are no longer holding. Now, maybe your question is what does it mean "a data distribution", this is just the joint law p(x, y) whe x are the features and y the labels. So two dataset have different distributions means that p_{1}(x, y) != p_{2}(x, y)

Comment: Thanks alot for your response.   When I read about 2 different distributions are 2 same features in 2 different projects, for example depth of inheritance tree (DIT) values of project1 is of different distribution from DIT values of project2 so it seems to be the difference in x values distribution between 2 data sets so only between each other as they were trying to put them in the same scale from (1-10)

Comment: Excuse me, another questions, does this assumption is valid on NN as well as it isn't a statistical learning problem as logistic regression for example

Comment: Fitting a neural network is also a statistical learning problem. The difference with logistic regression is that you are using a more complex parametric model. But the loss function that you optimize is roughly the  same. As a conclusion you need such an assumption, at least to have some sort of theoritical guarantes, even when you are using NNs